# multiselect product attribute not showing option labels on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, frontend, multiselect-attribute

I have checked lot and tried many things, but I am still not getting the product multiselect selected values label on product view page.

I have product attribute called package which is multiselect, 
Code that create the product attribute

```
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'package',
    array(
        'group'             => 'Package',
        'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'class'             => '',
        'default'           => '',
        'label'             => 'Package',
        'input'             => 'multiselect',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'source'            => 'npm_recurrex/package_source',
        'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'is_visible'        => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'searchable'        => 0,
        'filterable'        => 0,
        'unique'            => 0,
        'comparable'        => 0,
        'visible_on_front'  => 0,
        'user_defined'      => 1,
    )
);
```

this works fine, I am successfully saving the product.
But in frontend product view page when I say

```
Mage::log(print_r($_product->getData('package'), true));
```

Its prints the result as 1,2
But I wanted to display option labels of multiselect not option id's.
So I tried with this code

```
Mage::log(print_r($_product->getAttributeText('package'), true));
```

It prints nothing, just blank space :(.

I have checked this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34593/get-multiple-select-product-attributes-option-labels-instead-of-option-ids) but no use.

I am confused with this, Where I am wrong? and what is the wrong thing?

Can anybody explain me what is happening in my case?

my getOptionText Method

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == $value) {
            return $item['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getAttributeText` looks like this:

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

Notice the last 2 lines.
They mean that the method calls `getOptionText` from the source model class.
I see that your attribute has a custom source model `npm_recurrex/package_source`. Make sure that model has the method `getOptionText` or it's parent class has it and returns what your need.

**[EDIT]**
Your `getOptionText` is wrong.
It would work if the attribute would be of type `select`.
But it doesn't work for multiselects.
Here is a scenario. Actually I'm using your scenario.
`$_product->getData('package')` returns `1,2`.
And I assume your options are something like this:

```
$options[] => array('value' => 1, 'label'=>'Option 1');
$options[] => array('value' => 2, 'label'=>'Option 2');
$options[] => array('value' => 3, 'label'=>'Option 3');
$options[] => array('value' => 4, 'label'=>'Option 4');
```

In this case, your method receives as parameter `1,2` and you check if there is an element in `$options` with `value = 1,2`. and there isn't.
Try to make your method look like this:

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);
    $optionsByValue = array();
    foreach ($options as $item) {
        $optionsByValue[$item['value']] = $item['label'];
    }

    $values = explode(',', $value);
    $returnValue = array();
    foreach ($values as $_value) {
         if (isset($optionsByValue[$_value])) {
             $returnValue[] = $optionsByValue[$_value];
         }
    }
    return implode(', ', $returnValue);
}
```

Untested code so look out for typos.

Comment: Yes, My `getOptionText` method is present in `npm_recurrex/package_source` source model and it also contains the `getAllOptions`, `toOptionArray`, `getFlatColums`.

Comment: @Charlie Please post the `getOptionText ` method in the question

Comment: I have added the content of `getOptionText` Method

Comment: @Charlie. I've updated the code. See if it helps.

Comment: Yes, You are awesome, You finally helped lot me to get that issue. `getAttributeText` working now. Thank you Marius